# Connection problem with Laravel 5.7, php curl and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, curl, connection

I need help with a problem I have with PHP curl and Laravel 5.7.
I have been searching for several days but I have not found a solution.

When I connect to my WordPress web site with this PHP curl code 
I can reach the site and I can establish a connection.
The problem is when I click on the drop-down menu like edit my profile or I want to do some
administration things like edit a page, I am automatically logged out and brought back to the login page.

When I try my other websites, I have the same problem.

The same thing happens when I try to connect from the Laravel application to another Laravel application.
I am logged out and brought back to the login page.

You can try accessing with the credentials in the code.

Thank you for your help.

```
   $headr = array();
    $headr[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0";
    $headr[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $headr[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
    $headr[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $headr[] = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1";

    $postfields = array(
        'log' =>'john',
        'pwd' => '12345',
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://logiwebmedia.ca/wp/wp-login.php');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I can edit John Doe's profile, using Vivaldi.

Try another browser? Could be a cookie issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does not work with chrome and Firefox. I tried with Vivaldi it not work too.

Comment: How about using Opera, in VPN mode, so you are bypassing anything that maybe shaping the network traffic?